# Forge ARKit API - can't GET manifest after POST job

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

I've been working on Forge AR kit for several days. What I'm trying to do is to display and interact with APS(Forge) model in Unity. I followed [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/arvr-toolkit-refresher) step-by-step and refer to [this document](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/2.0.0#/) and meet some problems. Here's the details of my api calls (I test all api calls with Postman).

#### Get Token

I get token via **Authentication API v2**:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {My_Base_Code}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=data:read data:write data:create data:search bucket:create bucket:read bucket:update bucket:delete account:read account:write code:all'
```

#### Create Scene

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/arkit/v1/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dGVzdGJ1Y2tldF8yMDIzMDUyMi90ZXN0MS5ydnQ/scenes/test-scene' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {My_Token}' \
--data '{
    "prj":{
        "urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dGVzdGJ1Y2tldF8yMDIzMDUyMi90ZXN0MS5ydnQ"
    }
}'
```

I got following response with status `200`:

```
{
    "prj": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dGVzdGJ1Y2tldF8yMDIzMDUyMi90ZXN0MS5ydnQ"
    }
}
```

When I call `GET /arkit/v1/{urn}/scenes` I received `test-scene` in the response.

#### Create Scene Assets

```
curl --location --request POST 'developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/job' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {My_Token}' \
--data '{
  "input": {
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dGVzdGJ1Y2tldF8yMDIzMDUyMi90ZXN0MS5ydnQ"
  },
  "output": {
    "destination": {
      "region": "US"
    },
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "arkit",
        "scene": "test-scene"
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

I got status `200` with empty response body.

#### Check Scene Processing Status

```
curl --location --request GET 'developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dGVzdGJ1Y2tldF8yMDIzMDUyMi90ZXN0MS5ydnQ/manifest' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {My_Token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I always get response with status `404` here. Is it because it's still processing? or did I miss something? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You didnt spply http/https to the last 2 calls. Perhaps this is why

Comment: Thx for your advice. That's the problem. After adding `https://` in front of my url everything works. I'm sorry for the stupid question...

Answer (score 1):

While your question seems to have been answered by @BugFinder already, let me add a couple more details on the project itself:

The Forge AR/VR Toolkit used to be an experimental project, and I'm afraid it's  not being developed anymore. If you're interested in bringing your APS models into environments other than the Viewer, I'd suggest that you take a look at the [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) project instead. It's a Node.js module and a CLI tool that converts SVF models from Autodesk Platform Services into the popular, open 3D exchange format [glTF 2.0](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/main/specification/2.0). The glTF content can then be easily loaded into Unity, Unreal Engine, and other environments. The benefits of using the `forge-convert-utils` approach are:

- you have more control over the processing pipeline (i.e., you're not risking that a 3rd party pipeline will get sunset)
- you're future-proofing your solution as the Model Derivative service is planning to add glTF as native output in the future